# Django showing percentage of task completed/total task

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to make a simple django app which is like a todo app, I want to add the percentage of task completed.

Here's my model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

and here's the template file

```
<form method="POST" action="/">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form}}
        <input class="btn submit" type="submit" name="save">
    </form>

    {% for task in tasks %}
                {% if task.status == True %}
                <strike>{{task}}, {{task.complete_time}}</strike>
                {% else %}
                {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

and this is views.py file

```
def list(request):
    queryset = Task.objects.order_by('complete_time','complete_time')
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    context = {
    'tasks':queryset,
    'form':form,
    }
    return render(request, 'tasklist.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a class-based view

in views.py

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

class list(ListView):
    model = Task
    template_name = 'tasl_list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['get_percentage_done'] = Task.objects.filter(status = True).count() * 100 / Task.objects.all().count()
        return context
```

in your template

```
{{get_percentage_done}}
```